# Long Chapter heading trucated by Legrand Orange template

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

I am using the Legrand Orange book template (which seems to be quite popular so I am not posting its details here). A few of my chapter titles are too long and they are being truncated as shown in the attached image 1. Any idea how I can make it wrap the title.
[image]

I found one person was able to do something similar using KOMA script (see img 2) but I am not using that I am using the regular latex with TexWorks.
[image]

Please help.

thank you!

Comment: Where did you find that solution with KOMA? That you're using TeXworks is actually totally irrelevant, you should be able to use the KOMA version, though you may need to either install or upgrade the KOMA package first (depending on what exactly you currently have installed).

Comment: I saw this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257970/reproducing-the-chapter-picture-style-of-the-legrand-orange-book  and
https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25687

Comment: And if you try the first code block in the accepted answer, how does that fail?

Comment: To be honest, I was too lost in both of those links. He is not really using legrand orange but only trying to reproduce that look. So I am not sure what can I try from that. Legrand's main.tex contains this:
'\chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image
\chapter{Chapter dsaf  1234 asd fad fa 1234 dfa df adf 1234 f adsfasdfa d}'

Is there something that I have to do here? I am so sorry, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comments were probably not that helpful. `\chapterimage` is only for selecting the image used as the background. One has to make some changes in `structure.tex` (assuming the version you're using has the same setup as https://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book). I'll see if I can do it, but no promises.

Comment: Yes, structure.tex has quite a lot of hairy stuff. Sincerely appreciate you taking a look. Much obliged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book. In `structure.tex`, find lines 434 to 455. Those lines look like this:

```
434 \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
...
455 \fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}
```

Replace that entire block of 22 lines with the following:

```
\newlength\chaptertitleheight
\newsavebox\chaptertitlebox
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\setbox\chaptertitlebox=\hbox{%
\parbox{15cm}{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter\autodot~#1\strut}}
\setlength\chaptertitleheight{\dimexpr\ht\chaptertitlebox+\dp\chaptertitlebox}
\if@mainmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt,minimum height=1.2\chaptertitleheight]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node [text width=15cm] {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter\autodot~#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt,minimum height=1.2\chaptertitleheight]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node [text width=15cm] {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}
```

Four example pages with short and long, unnumbered and numbered, chapter titles:

[image]

Comment: YES!!! This works. Amazing. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If I may ask one more question, how do I move the title a little upwards to get more space for the page text below? I tried modifying several parameters in the above code and was able to change the width and height of the rounded box. But I couldn't move the whole thing up.

Comment: @Priyshrm Vertical position is determined by the `-9cm` you see at four different places. In `\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm)`,  `\Gm@lmargin` is the x-coordinate and `-9cm` the y-coordinate, relative to the top left corner of the page. Change `-9cm` to for example `-7cm`, or some other length that you find suitable.